# How to disable LAN from CMD in Win XP?

Tags: windows, shell

I want to disable my LAN from command prompt. For that, I have tried the command `netsh interface set interface Local Area Connection DISABLED`. I get an error saying:

```
Area is not an acceptable value for admin.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have admin rights and am on a 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess, quotes around multi word arguments:

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection" DISABLED
```

Comment: @CyprUS if it worked you should [check the checkmark](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) under the vote button and give Thorbjorn the credit for giving the correct answer.

Comment: It doesn't work on Win XP SP3. See my answer.

Comment: @Massimo it doesn't?  Really.  Why not?  (and your answer isn't)

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP SP3, italian

```
C:\>netsh interface show interface

Stato admin    Stato          Tipo             Nome interfaccia
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Abilitato                     Dedicato         Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)
Abilitato                     Interna          Interno
Abilitato                     Loopback         Loopback


C:\>netsh interface set interface name="Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)" admin=DISABLED

Uno o più parametri essenziali non sono stati specificati
Sintassi non valida. Consultare la guida per la sintassi corretta per il comando
```

Translation :

> One or more missing parameters. Syntax Error ...

The same error using

```
C:\>netsh interface set interface "Connessione alla rete locale (LAN)" DISABLED
```

Comment: Sorry I use the answer ( THIS ISN'T A ANSWER ) but in a comment I cannot include my tests with the right formatting.

Comment: it's probably because the accepted answer was aimed at a more recent windows version.